# Billing Cycle Date Range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, sql-server-2012

Code:

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate DATE = '2018-01-02' ;  -- Can be any date. This is just a date I used as an anchor point.
DECLARE @BillingDayOfMonth INT = 31 ;       -- The day of the billing every month (can be between 1st and 31st of the month).

;WITH [TT1] ( [N] ) AS
    (
        SELECT  1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  1
    )
    , [TT2] ( [N] ) AS
    (
        SELECT  1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  1
    )
    , [TT] ( [N] ) AS
    (
        SELECT      ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT NULL ) )
        FROM        [TT1] [T1]
        CROSS JOIN  [TT2] [T2]
    )
SELECT  [N]
FROM    [TT] ; -- This gives me the count of 12 cycles (can vary).
```

Goal:
To return current and X number of previous billing cycle dates (12 cycles total in the above example).

If the BillingDayOfMonth doesn't exists in a month (i.e. 29th to 31st depending on the month), choose the last day of the month as the BillingDayOfMonth. So if BillingDayOfMonth = 31st, this day doesn't exist in Nov. So The Cycle will start @11/30 instead of 11/31. The above code is incomplete and need your help figuring out an efficient solution. Thank you

Desired Output:

```
CycleStartDate  CycleEndDate
2017-12-31      2018-01-30      -- The most current cycle
2017-11-30      2017-12-30
2017-10-31      2017-11-29
2017-09-30      2017-10-30
2017-08-31      2017-09-29
2017-07-31      2017-08-30
2017-06-30      2017-07-30
2017-05-31      2017-06-29
2017-04-30      2017-05-30      -- Notice the EndDate
2017-03-31      2017-04-29      -- Notice the EndDate
2017-02-28      2017-03-30      -- Notice the StartDate
2017-01-31      2017-02-27      -- Notice the EndDate
```

Answer (score 1):

So based on your numbers table approach and your rules, you can use a query like below.

I tested this for  @BillingDayOfMonth values like 25, 28, 30 and found results reasonably true.

<kbd>**[See live demo](http://rextester.com/AWGV33875)**</kbd>

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate DATE = '2018-01-02' ;  -- Can be any date. This is just a date I used as an anchor point.
DECLARE @BillingDayOfMonth INT = 31 ;       -- The day of the billing every month (can be between 1st and 31st of the month).
DECLARE @StartDate DATE
SET @StartDate=   CASE WHEN 
                       DAY(EOMONTH(@CurrentDate)) < @BillingDayOfMonth
                       THEN
                       EOMONTH(@CurrentDate)
                       ELSE
                       DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@CurrentDate),MONTH(@CurrentDate),@BillingDayOfMonth)
                   END

;WITH [TT1] ( [N] ) AS
    (
        SELECT  1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  1
    )
    , [TT2] ( [N] ) AS
    (
        SELECT  1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  1
    )
    , [TT] ( [N] ) AS
    (
        SELECT    
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT NULL ) )

        FROM        [TT1] [T1]
        CROSS JOIN  [TT2] [T2]
    )

SELECT  CycleStartDate  = 
                    DATEADD(M,-N,@StartDate)
        ,
        CycleEndDate    =
                    DATEADD(D,-1,DATEADD(M,1-N,@StartDate))

FROM    [TT] ;
```

Comment: This is a neat solution. Thanks. Just one thing though. When CurrentDate = '2018-01-02' AND BillingDayOfMonth IS either 01 (new cycle started yesterday) OR 02 (new cycle started today), can we have '2018-01-01' TO '2018-01-31' (for 01) '2018-01-02' TO '2018-02-01' (for 02) as the most recent result? Basically, on '2018-01-02', you're already in the '01/01' or ('01/02') to '01/31' (or '02/1') cycle.